# Time Series Forecasting with RNN/LSTM/NARX

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, forecasting, sequence

I have some experimental datasets (like 4 or 5), and each dataset has three time series data, say $u1(t)$, $u2(t)$, and $x(t)$. The three time series of each experiment are similar but not the same. How can I train my model to learn the relation between the series, such that when a new $u1(t)$ and $u2(t)$ come in, I can predict the $x(t)$ in real-time?